# Did I disrespect the Buddha on the altar?

Tags: karma, statue

Why do we close a question about trying to find out if I’m disrespecting The Buddha, I learned I should not look at my altar when I’m angry or disappointed. see I’m so angry right now I don’t think I can look at my altar. I just wanted to know. And then you guess closed my question. It wasn’t offensive, in any way. I was clear, I think ,I just deleted the message after I tried to please you. I just wanted to know know if I’m disrespecting The Buddha.

Answer (score 2):

The sutta below states that a memorial shrine or monument or stupa (and by extension, a statue or painting) is meant for making the mind of the beholder calm and happy. It's a source of inspiration.

So, you don't have to feel guilty or avoid looking at the Buddha icon when you feel negative emotions.

Instead, you should look at it exactly when you need to feel calmness and peace, and reflect on who the Buddha is, what he attained and what he taught.

> "There are four persons, Ananda, who are worthy of a stupa. Who are
> those four? A Tathagata, an Arahant, a Fully Enlightened One is worthy
> of a stupa; so also is a Paccekabuddha, and a disciple of a Tathagata,
> and a universal monarch.
>
> "And why, Ananda, is a Tathagata, an Arahant, a Fully Enlightened One
> worthy of a stupa? Because, Ananda, at the thought: 'This is the stupa
> of that Blessed One, Arahant, Fully Enlightened One!' **the hearts of
> many people will be calmed and made happy**; and so calmed and with
> their minds established in faith therein, at the breaking up of the
> body, after death, they will be reborn in a realm of heavenly
> happiness. And so also at the thought: 'This is the stupa of that
> Paccekabuddha!' or 'This is the stupa of a disciple of that Tathagata,
> Arahant, Fully Enlightened One!' or 'This is the stupa of that
> righteous monarch who ruled according to Dhamma!' — the hearts of many
> people are calmed and made happy; and so calmed and with their minds
> established in faith therein, at the breaking up of the body, after
> death, they will be reborn in a realm of heavenly happiness. And it is
> because of this, Ananda, that these four persons are worthy of a
> stupa."
> [DN 16](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at your alter *especially* when your mind is angry or disappointed. This will help your mind to come to its senses.

The Buddha is the Spiritual Doctor. When your mind is sick, it should visit the Buddha. If you don't visit Doctor Buddha when your mind is sick, how will your mind find a cure & heal itself?

Comment: Thank you! Now I’m wondering why someone else who has be a Buddhist a lot longer than I have not want to look at my altar, when I may have upset them? I thought because they did not look at my altar, that meant I should not look at my altar because I got angry?

Comment: some folks have extreme views about things, particularly tibetans

Comment: thank you but your comment is not relevant to my answer

Comment: Thank you, sorry, I was just a bit defensive about the Tibetan heritage. But I had defend one of my staff, who is Tibetan. From an angry man. I was afraid for her safety, so I lost control of myself, to scare him away.